Shorten both ends of TikZ arrow
The following code shortens both ends of the arrow so as to move them away from the nodes. Is there show way to shorten both ends with a single option (instead of the two shorten options I show)?
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\A {(0,0)}; \def\B {(1,0)};
    \filldraw[gray!30] \A circle (2pt);
    \filldraw[gray!30] \B circle (2pt);
    \draw[<-,shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]  \A -- \B  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



As far as I know, such a key does not exist. But you can simply create your own custom style (and I'd use \coordinates instead of \def):
\documentclass[tikz, border=1pt]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    shorten <>/.style={
        shorten <=#1,
        shorten >=#1
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
    \filldraw[gray!30] (A) circle[radius=2pt];
    \filldraw[gray!30] (B) circle[radius=2pt];
    \draw[<-, shorten <>=4pt] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You could add a default value <>/.default=4pt, which would be more practical in use.
